# Trying to create a same empty file using AWS s3.put_object by more than one process in parallel using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Suppose if two(it can be any number) processes are trying to access same block of code in parallel, to avoid that parallel access, I am trying to create an empty file in s3 bucket, so that if that file exists, then other process which is trying to access has to wait before the first process ends up using the block of code. After its usage the first process will delete the empty file which means that the second process can now be able to use that block of code by creating the empty file and holds the lock with it.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def create_obj(bucket, file):      
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file)
    return "file created"

job1 = create_obj(bucket="s3bucketname", file='xyz/empty_file.txt')
job2 = create_obj(bucket="s3bucketname", file='xyz/empty_file.txt')
```

Here suppose job1 and job2 are trying to access the same create_obj in parallel to create `empty_file.txt`, which means they are hitting the line `s3.put_object` at the same time. Then one of the jobs has to wait. Here n number of jobs can access the `create_obj` function in parallel. We need to make sure that those jobs execute properly as explained above.

Please help me with this.

Comment: So you're trying to implement a distributed lock based on S3?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you're trying to implement a distributed locking mechanism on the basis of S3.

Since the updates to the S3 consistency model at re:invent 2020 this could be possible, but you could also use a service like DynamoDB for it, which makes building these easier.

I recommend you check out [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/) on the AWS blog, which describes the process. Since link-only answers are discouraged here, I'll try to summarize the idea, but you should really read the full article.

1. You do a conditional `PutItem` call on a lock-item in the table. The condition is, that an item with that key doesn't exist or has expired. The new item contains:

   - The name of the lock (Partition Key)
   - How long that lock is supposed to be valid
   - Timestamp when the lock was created
   - Some identifier that identifies your system (the locking entity)
2. If that put works, you know that you have acquired the lock, if it fails you know it's already locked and can retry later
3. You then perform your work
4. In the end you remove the lock item

There's an implementation of this for Python as well [python-dynamodb-lock on PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/python-dynamodb-lock/)

Comment: Thank U for your response. But I need python based solution and we are not having services like DynamoDB. Can you help me in implementing using python??

Comment: I've added a link for the Python Implementation for DynamoDB. I can't help you achieve this with S3, it's best to use a system with features that are actually designed to solve distributed locking problems...

Comment: Okay. I will refer it.